# Concatenating b64 String Only Works For Small Pictures

Tags: javascript, php

I am working with some code that uploads a picture by splitting it into chunks.

```
           $('#image-file').on('change',function(){
                    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
                        var file = this.files[0];
                        var fileSize   = file.size;
                        var chunkSize  = 64 * 1024; // bytes
                        var offset     = 0;
                        var self       = this; // we need a reference to the current object
                        var chunkReaderBlock = null;
                        var allImgData = "";

                        var readEventHandler = function(e) {
                            if (e.target.error == null) {
                                offset += chunkSize;

                                imgData = e.target.result.split(",");
                                imgData = imgData[1];

                                console.log(imgData);

                                allImgData += atob(imgData);


                            } else {
                                console.log("Read error: " + e.target.error);
                                return;
                            }

                            if (offset >= fileSize) {

                                var formData = {
                                    'name'              : localStorage.getItem('email'),
                                    'image'             : btoa(allImgData)
                                };


                                 $.ajax({
                                     type   : 'POST',
                                     url    : '/uploadprofile.php',
                                     data   : formData,
                                     dataType: 'json',
                                     encode : true
                                }).done(function(data) {
                                      console.log(data);
                                });
                                return;
                            }

                            // of to the next chunk
                            chunkReaderBlock(offset, chunkSize, file);
                        }

                        chunkReaderBlock = function(_offset, length, _file) {
                            var r = new FileReader();
                            var blob = _file.slice(_offset, length + _offset);
                            r.onload = readEventHandler;
                            r.readAsDataURL(blob);
                        }

                        // now let's start the read with the first block
                        chunkReaderBlock(offset, chunkSize, file);


                    }
                });
```

This code works as long as the number of chunks is relatively low i.e small pictures get uploaded just fine, but bigger ones give an error. I found that for some reason around 2MB the PHP file I'm using returns POST http://tanglecollege.com/uploadprofile.php 406 (Not Acceptable). I know that the POST limit for my php.ini is around 256MB so this isn't the problem. 
I made sure to use atob to concantenate the chunks, as well as removing the initial data that describes the b64 string. When I send it to the PHP file I use btoa in order to return it into binary string form. My PHP file returns the error POST http://tanglecollege.com/uploadprofile.php 406 (Not Acceptable), even when all I do is read in the data.
Why is it that larger images split into chunks are unable to be uploaded even when smaller pictures that are split into chunks are?

Comment: Have you verified that the 406 is coming from PHP not from the webserver interpreting it?

Comment: How would I check that?

Comment: Make the PHP code write something to the logs when it's returning an error status such as 406. Also check the webserver error and access logs.